# Django model introspection - regular many to many Vs through many to many

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model with 2 many to many relations to the same model.

One of them, uses the "through" options, like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    property1 = models.ManyToManyField(Model2, related_name="internal", blank=True, null=True)
    property2 = models.ManyToManyField(
        Model2,
        related_name="external",
        through="Model3"
    )
```

While iterating over model_instance._meta.m2m_data how can I check for "property2"?

both fields have "rel.through" set.. I was expecting just the second field.. while in the first one I would have "rel.to" but not "rel.through"

Answer (score 1):

In my own example, when field is propery1, `is_hidden()` would return `True`, because there is this concept about hidden relationship. Also, `property2.rel.id_hidden()` would return `False` since `Model3` represents this relationship.

```
# for some reason, User.groups has field.is_hidden() == None
if field.rel.is_hidden() == None:
    hidden_field = True
else:
    hidden_field = field.rel.is_hidden()
```

Usage here: https://github.com/felipecruz/dmqs/blob/master/dmqs/integration/memorify_django_model.py#L28